# How do i pick the first,second, third, and fourth key separately in a dictionary

Tags: python

Basically i have a dictionary with values such as, "Couple1" : 2, "Couple2" : 3 and so on.

I want to pick out the first key and the second key and the third key separately. So i want it to be as, print(the first key) print(the second key)

i tried remaining[0] to get the first key but that doesnt work

```
eliminate = {"Couple1":Couple1,"Couple2":Couple2,"Couple3":Couple3,"Couple4":Couple4,"Couple5":Couple5,"Couple6":Couple6}
```

I want to pick out the first key so "Couple1" then "Couple2" then "Couple3"

It gave me an error every time i tried to do something so im just completely lost.

Comment: there are no first & second, ... keys. you just want to iterate on the dict itself to get the keys `for x in eliminate: print(x)`

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Starting in Python 3.7, dictionaries *do* have a reliable order now, namely the order in which the keys were added (which corresponds to the order in which they appear in a `dict` literal).

Comment: @chepner true, deleted comment so as to not mislead, re insertion order.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Life was simpler when `dict`s *didn't* have any notion of key order :)

Answer (score 0):

please try this

it iterate through the dict and store the keys in a list , then you can access the element you want from the list which will be a key

```
eliminate = {"Couple1":1,"Couple2":2,"Couple3":3,"Couple4":4,"Couple5":5,"Couple6":6}


s = []

for key, value in eliminate.items() :
    s.append(key)
```